# Optimize C++ function to generate combinations

Tags: c++, math, optimization, combinations

I'm trying to get a function to generate all possible combinations of numbers but my problem is the too long elaboration time. So I think I've to optimize it.
Problem: Generate all set of "r" size with 1 to n elements without repeat it in reverse order (1,2 is equal to 2, 1).

Example:

```
n = 3 //elements: 1,2,3
r = 2 //size of set

Output:
2 3
1 3
1 2
```

The code I'm using is the following:

```
    void func(int n, int r){
        vector <vector <int>> reas;
        vector<bool> v(n);
        fill(v.end() - r, v.end(), true);

        int a = 0;
        do {
            reas.emplace_back();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                if (v[i]) {
                    reas[a].push_back(i+1);
                }
            }
            a++;
        } while (next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
    }
```

If n = 3 and r = 2 the output will be the same of the example upside. 
My problem is that if I put n = 50 and r = 5 the elaboration time is too high and I need to work with a range of n = 50...100 and r= 1..5;
Is there a way to optimize this function?

Thank's a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are several things you can improve significantly. However, you should keep in mind that the number of combinations you are calculating is so large, that it *has* to be slow if it is to enumerate all subsets. On my machine and with my personal patience budget `(100,5)` is out of reach.

Given that, here are the things you can improve without completely rewriting your entire algorithm.

---

### First: Cache locality

A `vector<vector<T>>` will not be contiguous. The nested vector is rather small, so even with preallocation this will always be bad, and iterating over it will be slow because each new sub-vector (and there are **a lot**) will likely cause a cache miss.

Hence, use a single `vector<T>`. Your `k`th subset will then not sit at location `k` but at `k*r`. But this is a significant speedup on my machine.

### Second: Use a cpu-friendly permutation vector

Your idea to use `next_permutation` is not bad. But the fact that you use a `vector<bool>` makes this extremely slow. Paradoxically, using a `vector<size_t>` is **much** faster, because it is easier to load a `size_t` and check it than it is to do the same with a `bool`.

So, if you take these together the code looks something like this:

```
  auto func2(std::size_t n, std::size_t r){
    std::vector<std::size_t> reas;
    reas.reserve((1<<r)*n);
    std::vector<std::size_t> v(n);
    std::fill(v.end() - r, v.end(), 1); 

    do {
      for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (v[i]) {
          reas.push_back(i+1);
        }
      }   
    } while (std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
    return reas;
  }
```

### Third: Don't press the entire result into one huge buffer

Use a callback to process each sub-set. Thereby you avoid having to return one huge vector. Instead you call a function for each individual sub-set that you found. If you really really need to have one huge set, this callback can still push the sub-sets into a vector, but it can also operate on them in-place.

```
  std::size_t func3(std::size_t n, std::size_t r, 
                    std::function<void(std::vector<std::size_t> const&)> fun){
    std::vector<std::size_t> reas;
    reas.reserve(r);
    std::vector<std::size_t> v(n);
    std::fill(v.end() - r, v.end(), 1);

    std::size_t num = 0;
    do {
      reas.clear(); // does not shrink capacity to 0
      for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (v[i]) {
          reas.push_back(i+1);
        }
      }
      ++num;
      fun(reas);
    } while (std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
    return num;
  }
```

**This yields a speedup of well over 2x in my experiments. But the speedup goes up the more you crank up `n` and `r`.**

### Also: Use compiler optimisation

Use your compiler options to speed up the compilation as much as possible. On my system the jump from -O0 to -O1 is a speedup of well more than 10x. The jump to -O3 from -O1 is much smaller but still there (about x1.1).

---

Unrelated to performance, but still relevant: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)